# Call cloudant db service, got error javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, ssl, cloudant

Our code deployed on bluecloud server, and needs to touch the cloudant db service located in bluemix env, got below error when trying touch the db.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: Error retrieving server response at https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com:443/server/_find.] with root cause

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

Code worked fine on my local, issues only found in bluecloud server, can someone help on this? Thanks.

PS: Maven dependency of cloudant client in my code is com.cloudant.cloudant-client.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant requires TLS 1.2 or higher so it sounds like your version of Java is too low.

Source: [get SSLException error when trying to connect cloudant db #496](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/issues/496)